# error C2955 and error C2244 using C++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm starting learning C++ template.
Now, I'm trying to compile the simple example of C++ template.

```
#include <iostream.h>
template <class T> class pair1 {
     T value1, value2;
public:
    pair1 (T first, T second) {
        value1=first;
        value2=second;
    }
    T getmax ();
};

template <class T> 
T pair1::getmax (){
     T retval;
    retval = value1>value2? value1 : value2;
    return retval;
}
int main(){
     pair1<int> myobject (100, 75);
    cout << myobject.getmax()<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I occured the following 2 errors:

- (1) error C2955: 'pair1':use of template requires template argument
  list
- (2) error C2244:'pair1::getmax':unable to match function
  definition to an existing declaration

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010.

When use inline function as following, it worked fined:

```
#include <iostream.h>
template <class T> class pair1 {
     T value1, value2;
public:
    pair1 (T first, T second) {
        value1=first;
        value2=second;
    }
   **T getmax (){ T retval;
retval = value1>value2? value1 : value2;
return retval;};**
};


int main(){
     pair1<int> myobject (100, 75);
    cout << myobject.getmax()<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

However, i prefer not using inline function in this situation,
hope anyone can tell what's wrong with the first block of C++ template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use template parameter for class.

```
template <class T> 
T pair1<T>::getmax (){
     T retval;
    retval = value1>value2? value1 : value2;
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: how is this different from what he has used?

Comment: @Aniket, how about T parameter?

Comment: Oh right yeah, he has two codes posted. I was looking at the second one trying to figure out what was wrong with it!