# Return Node in template class

Tags: c++

I am trying to use templates as a universal (as it should be) member to hold the GUI component of my menu. I am trying to use nodes to create a menu and I am getting these two errors C2244 and C2955. I have looked at those errors and compared them to my code and cannot seem to find my issue.

I didn't include a constructor definition because the issue is a compiler error.

Compiler errors if you are to lazy to read the paragraph:

**Error 1:**

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2244 'GUI::MenuNode<ui_Interface>::select': unable to match function 
definition to an existing declaration
```

AND

**Error 2:**

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2955 j'GUI::MenuNode': use of class template requires template 
argument list
```

```
template<class ui_Interface>

class MenuNode {
private:
    shared_ptr<MenuNode> itself;
    vector<shared_ptr<MenuNode>> nodes;
    ui_Interface *u_Interface;
public:
    //returns the address of the newly selected node
    //itself if nothing is to be returned
    const MenuNode& select();
    //returns interface member
    ui_Interface getInterface();
    MenuNode();
    ~MenuNode();
};



template<class ui_Interface>
const MenuNode & MenuNode<ui_Interface>::select() { //Errors occur here
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        if (nodes[i]->getInterface().mouseSelect()) {
            return *nodes[i];
        }
    }
    return *itself;
}
```

Comment: Any error details?

Comment: Yes they were in the paragraph

Comment: You appear to be too lazy to post the text of those errors, and an indication of where they occurred in your code.

Comment: If you post questions about build errors, then please *copy-paste* the errors, as text, in full, complete, without modifications and including any possible informational notes. We need that in the body of the question. And while editing your question to include the errors, also please mark out the lines in the code you show where the errors happen, with e.g. comments. I suggest you take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't done it yet. And if you have, then please read it again.

Comment: ok i fixed it my bad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C2955 and error C2244 using C++ template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129038/error-c2955-and-error-c2244-using-c-template)

Comment: Don't think so. I read his code and his problem was he forgot to add the template parameter in his function definition T pair1::getmax () where it should be T pair1<T>::getmax (). I didn't have this issue.

Comment: I made it work just from looking at his code I'll post the solution

Comment: I am sure someone posted the correct one it was `const MenuNode<ui_Interface> & MenuNode<ui_Interface>::`

Comment: TY i should post this as an answer the the problem. I am kinda new to templates. Would I need to do this for every single getter function?

Comment: @Dogunboundhounds The reason for all of this is that inside the scope of your class template, plain `MenuNode` can be used as a typedef for the full name `MenuNode<ui_Interface>` (this is called the "injected class name").  But when defining a member outside the class definition, you're not yet inside the class scope until you've named the class member (like `select`).  So a return type which involves the template name will always need the long version, unless you switch to a "trailing return type" syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment suggested by Tyger I simply didn't put the template declaration on the getter method.

This is what it should look like

```
    const MenuNode<ui_Interface> & MenuNode<ui_Interface>::select() {
          //some code here
    }
```

This is what it used to look like

```
        //missing <ui_Interface> after the first MenuNode
    const MenuNode & MenuNode<ui_Interface>::select() {
          //some code here
    }
```